# Is there a way to disable Intel SpeedStep on an Ubuntu Server using a command line application?

Tags: 12.04, server, performance

We cannot disable it using the BIOS, because Turbo gets turned off as well as a side effect (what a crappy BIOS!). I am looking for a simple command line tool for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server that can do this.

I know on Windows, if you set the Power Options to High Performance, SpeedStep is disabled, but how can I do this on Ubuntu Linux using a command line application?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable SpeedStep, you would run cpufrequtils.  It should already be installed on your system if you're running a Gnome desktop.  If not you can install it by clicking below

[image]

Once you install it, you would run

```
 sudo cpufreq-selector -g performance
```

However, running the CPU at full speed, may cause it to shutdown after a few minutes.

```
sudo cpufreq-selector -f <specify speed>
```

To verify your CPU speed, use the "cat" utility:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: I believe the performance governor still varies the cpu frequency, just less aggressively than the powersave one.  Also you have to set the governor for each logical core.